# Is statebase framework such as Lift Scalable?

Tags: scala, lift

I've watch Harry Heymann, from Foursquare, gave a presentation on Lift to BASE usergroup. He mention something about how Lift being statebase isn't going to scale well in that video.

Is that true? If so why is that? Note: I know very little about state base.

I can't seem to find the google, I'll look for it later. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When this questions comes up on the Lift Mailing list, what the author of the framework usually replies with is a blog post he wrote some time ago, which explains why Lift is Stateful, but at the same time how you **can** use Lift as a stateless framework.

This is the [link](http://lift.la/lift-state-and-scaling)

Answer (score 4):

David Pollack has a good answer to this at this [this Quora thread](http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-writing-a-web-app-in-Scala-using-Lift), in a comment to Jackson Davis's answer:

> *In practice, scaling a Lift site is much much easier than scaling a LAMP site.  Why?  Well, state exists someplace.  If it exists in the JVM, you get a lot of performance benefits and stability as well as, in Lift's case, lots of security.  Contrast that with sessions in memcached.  "Whoop, memcached went down, there go a pile of sessions."  "Whoops, we've got a new memcached hashing algorithm, there go all the session."  "Whoops, Google just crawled us creating 200,000 new sessions pushing all the but the active sessions out of cache."  "Whoops, the Ruby runtime just went wild, ate all the VM on one of our boxes, memcached went down..."  So, you try storing sessions in some wacky shared version of MySQL.  This solution requires tons of hardware and a team of make sure that the sharing code is correct, etc.  Contrast that to using Nginx, Jetty and session affinity.  It's about 4 hours of setup time and it just works.  See http://blog.harryh.org/post/7550...  So, talk to a Facebook engineer about the challenges they go through to manage state between the front end, memcached, MySQL, etc.  Compare that to Twitter with the famous fail whale.  Compare that to Apple's store and the iTunes store which are written on WebObject (which is highly stateful.)  Lift apps running at scale typically require 7% of the front end resources of LAMP app.  The Lift apps that are running at scale (Foursquare and Novell pulse are two) do not have the kind of scaling issues associated with LAMP sites that have similar traffic patterns.  Scaling with Lift is neither tricky, nor risky.  It's simple.  It's known.  It's proven.  Scaling with LAMP is playing whack-a-mole with state and that only becomes a problem at scale.  -David Pollak • Jul 20, 2010*

Answer (score 2):

I think it's pretty clear that Lift apps scale very well. Foursquare and the UK Guardian are both using Lift.  Both sites are very highly trafficked and neither has had a material Lift-related outage.  Please also see the link that Diego posted.  It provides an in-depth discussion of scaling Lift-powered sites.